# How can I get the id of a user just by writing their email in php?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating an endpoint to be able to send an email to a user in case they have forgotten their password, just entering their email to be able to send them an email to reset a new password, I only need to be able to obtain the id of said email that they enter to change your password in php mailer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a built-in WordPress function that can get a user ID by email address:

Try `get_user_by()` see here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/

*Please note that this function does not return the user ID, but a `WP_User` object (which includes the user ID)*

Also note that WordPress already have a password reset function for users, here are the instructions for a password reset: https://wordpress.org/support/article/resetting-your-password/#through-the-automatic-emailer

In addition, as @maggiathor commented, there is also a WordPress function to initiate a password reset programmatically called `retrieve_password()` see here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/retrieve_password/

Comment: I think you meant to add that link to your comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/retrieve_password/

Comment: Actually, I wanted to add this link: https://wordpress.org/support/article/resetting-your-password/#through-the-automatic-emailer because resetting a password in WordPress is something  users can usually do by themselves. I will edit both links into my answer - thanks @maggiathor